# How to update a variable in "realtime" using functions which take many seconds to return a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, real-time, sensors

What logic should be used to update a variable such as a current mean in real time?

For example in the script below `obs_mean()` produces a mean by listening to incoming sensor data. The function `listen_to_observations()` is an example function which behaves similarly to the real sensor data function.

How can the value `current_mean` be updated **every second/realtime** using `obs_mean(5)` (which takes 5 seconds worth of data and takes 5 seconds to return a value)?

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time

current_mean = None

def listen_to_observations():
    #listen to a stream of observations
    time.sleep(1)
    yield random.random()

def obs_mean(seconds):
    array = [listen_to_observations().next() for i in range(seconds)]
    return np.array(array).mean()
```

How would the logic look like? I am using Python 3.5.

Comment: If the mean is computed after every 5 seconds, then what's the use in updating the "current_mean" variable? It'll ofcourse, will stay the same until you compute the new mean.

Comment: Not exactly. If the function `obs_mean(5)` is called at 10:00:00, it will return the value at 10:00:05. at 10:00:06 however it is possible to have an updated value for observations from 10:00:01 to 10:00:06. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just break up your array line into separate statements, and compute the mean after every observation:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import time

current_mean = None

def listen_to_observations():
    #listen to a stream of observations
    time.sleep(1)
    yield random.random()

def obs_mean(seconds):
    array = []
    for i in range(seconds):    
        array.append(listen_to_observations().next())
        current_mean = np.array(array).mean()
        print('current_mean = {}'.format(current_mean))
    return current_mean

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obs_mean(5)
```

*My output:*

```
current_mean = 0.193142347659
current_mean = 0.212120380098
current_mean = 0.355774933848
current_mean = 0.362840457341
current_mean = 0.312662693142
```